# Entity framework core get single child from of parent child collection

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using entity framework core and have simple table structure where system has many logs, but for my certain functionality I want to have last child of that collection so i tried:

```
Models.Entities.System system = await Context.Systems
   .Include(log => log.MaintenanceLogs)
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(system=> system.Id == system);
```

But as i know I can not add

```
.Include(log => log.MaintenanceLogs).Last()
```

Well it will not work, I could create manual query and get what I want, but that is not the point. 
Also I can get all logs and get last after query materializes but still there can be whole lot of that logs db records and I need only last so why waste resources.

Reason is that I need to get one value from last log and base on that value update system ( of course all in transaction ).

Can it be done ?

Comment: Order by log date descending, then Take(1), then call FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Although it may not even be necessarry to call Take(1) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do

```cs
Models.Entities.MaintenanceLog log = await Context.MaintenanceLogs
   .Include(log => log.System)
   .LastOrDefaultAsync(log => log.System.Id == system);
```

instead? You know, switch it around.

This would only fetch a last entry in MaintenanceLogs table where the `System.Id` is equal to the value of `system` variable.